# VBA code to move columns of only newly pasted rows of data

Tags: excel, vba, copy

[image]

As shown the mocked-up table above, i'm trying write a macro that copies new data from another workbook (OtherWorkBook), then pastes it below the existing database (in ThisWorkBook).

After that, for **only the new rows of data that was pasted**, i want to shift the values in columns A, B, C, D one cell to the right. My current code works right until when it is supposed to move the columns, but then an error shows up.

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim DestLastRow As Long
Dim ToCopy As Range
Dim ToPaste As Range

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("OtherWorkBook").Worksheets("OtherWorkSheet")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("ThisWorkBook").Worksheets("ThisWorkSheet")
    
CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  wsCopy.Range("A2:V" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)

    Set ToCopy = wsCopy.Range("A2:V" & CopyLastRow)
    Set ToPaste = wsDest.Range("A" & PasteToLastRow)
    
    ToCopy.Copy ToPaste
    
    Set ToPaste = ToPaste.Resize(ToCopy.Rows.Count, ToCopy.Columns.Count)
    ToPaste.Columns("A:D").Cut

'The debugger highlights this line of code
    ToPaste.Columns("D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

[image]

A macro recorder would not be feasible as the macro is periodically executed to add in new rows of data

Comment: Please show the code you are trying.  One thing is you will want to ensure there are no merged cells.

Comment: added as requested

Comment: `Range("E:E").ClearContents` then `Range(A:A).Insert`

Comment: I tried it but the same error code pops up

Comment: That is in place of the code you have.

Comment: Yes, it still shows me the error

Comment: It cannot be the same as there is no copy paste.

Comment: made extra edits to better clarify my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say *move the values*, so you could use `Range.Value` rather than Cut/Paste

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim DestLastRow As Long
    Dim ToCopy As Range
    Dim ToPaste As Range
    
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("OtherWorkBook").Worksheets("OtherWorkSheet")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("ThisWorkBook").Worksheets("ThisWorkSheet")
        
    CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    ' deleted redundant Copy/Paste here

    Set ToCopy = wsCopy.Range("A2:V" & CopyLastRow)
    Set ToPaste = wsDest.Range("A" & PasteToLastRow)
        
    ' copy the data
    ToCopy.Copy ToPaste
    
    ' Resize ToPaste to the pasted rows, 4 columns
    Set ToPaste = ToPaste.Resize(ToCopy.Rows.Count, 4)
    ' Move first 4 columns 1 column to right, leave formatting intact
    ToPaste.Offset(, 1).Value = ToPaste.Value
    ' Clear the first column
    ToPaste.Columns(1).ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Columns("D").Cut
Columns("E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C").Cut
Columns("D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("B").Cut
Columns("C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("A").Cut
Columns("B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Unfortunately, don't have my Microsoft Office computer open to check whether this works, but you should be able to get the gist of my suggested solution from the above.

Comment: i've added more lines of code in my edit that might be causing my issue